# What's the difference between corms, bulbs, and tubers?

Tags: growth, roots, terminology

Some plants, such as [tulips](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tulip), [daffodils](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Narcissus_(plant)), and [onions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Onion), grow from bulbs. Others, such as [crocosmia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crocosmia), [gladiolus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gladiolus), and [taro](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taro), grow from corms. And then there are tuberous plants, such as [potatoes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Potato), [dahlias](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dahlia), and [begonias](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Begonia_%C3%97_tuberhybrida). These are the most common underground storage organs in plants.

How do I distinguish between them?

Comment: Also see: [Weekly topic challenge: terminology](http://meta.gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/602/weekly-topic-challenge-terminology).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Bulbs

[Bulbs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bulb) are plant storage organs generally grown underground, consisting of a short stem (the basal plate), from which grow overlapping, swollen leaves or leaf bases. The top growth emerges from the bulb center. Here's an example:

[image]

## Corms

[Corms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Corm) are not made up of leaves, but a vertical swollen compact stem, and as such are solid. The corm is protected by a tunic of old leaf petioles. Here's an example:

[image]

## Tubers

[Tubers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tuber) are, simply, enlargements in the underground stem or lateral root of a plant that are used for food storage. These vary greatly in appearance, but all have the same function. Here's an example:

[image]